# How to sum all integer after running a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written a script, but I don't know if it's possible to have the total.  My script would give me total number per loop, but I want to have the lump sum of everything.  For instance, if I input 6, I would expect the result to be 168.  if I input 5, I would expect the result to be 105.

Thanks

My script is as follow:

```
def multiples(n, high):
    i = 0
    res = 0
    while i <= high:
        res = res + (n+i)
        i = i + 1
    print res
    return res

def p(high):
    i = 1
    while i <= high:
        multiples(i, i)
        i = i + 1

p(6)  # Expected Output: 168
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a cumulative sum function? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Comment: This indentation will get you an indentation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things,

First off, this is a very old-school type of looping.

```
i = 0
while i <= some_number:
    do_something
    i = i + 1
```

The last language I used that required a pattern like that was Basic. Use `for` loops. A standard `for` loop (note: NOT Python's, but I'll get to that in a minute) looks like `for i=0; i<=some_number; i++ { do_something }`. That is:

1. Initialize `i`
2. Conditional for when to keep looping
3. What to do after each loop block

Python is even more clear. `for` loops over any iterable, so:

```
for element in [1,3,5,7,9]:
    ...
```

Gives you `1`, then `3`, then `5`, then `7`, then `9` as `element` in the loop body. Use this in conjunction with the `range` built-in to loop `N` times.

```
for i in range(high):
    # do something `high` number of times
```

A naive re-write looks like:

```
def multiples(k, n):
    res = 0
    for i in range(n):
        res += (k+i)
    print(res)
    return res

def p(n):
    for i in range(n):
        multiples(i, i)
```

However that doesn't really give you what you want either. What you WANT is to assign the value `multiples(i, i)` TO something.

```
def p(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        total += multiples(i, i)
    return total
```

Now we're tracking your grand total inside `p`, and returning it afterwards.

```
result = p(6)
print(result)  # does what you want
```

---

Of course there's no good reason to break up these two functions. You could just as easily write:

```
def p(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            total += j+i
    return total
```

Comment: Note that depending on what you're trying to do, I may have introduced an off-by-one error. Your original implementation loops from `1 -> N, while mine loops from `0 -> N-1`. This isn't an issue in `multiples` but might be in `p`. Fix this with `for i in range(1, n+1)` instead of `for i in range(n)`

Answer (score 0):

With the most minimal change, this would allow `p(6)` to return `168`:

```
def multiples(n, high):
   i = 0
   res = 0
   while i <= high:
      res = res + (n+i)
      i = i + 1
   print res
   return res

def p(high):
   i = 1
   lumpSum = 0
   while i <= high:
      lumpSum += multiples(i, i)
      i = i + 1
   return lumpSum

print p(6)
```

Alternatively, you can shorten `p`:

```
def p(high):
    return sum([multiples(i, i) for i in range(1, high + 1)])
```

Edit: The entire code can indeed be reduced to this: [Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith) pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882132/how-to-sum-all-integer-after-running-a-loop/38882236?noredirect=1#comment65125810_38882236).

`p = lambda n: sum(i+j for i in range(n) for j in range(i))`

Comment: or indeed `p = lambda n: sum(i+j for i in range(n) for j in range(i))`